# Conditionally add records to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a roster of baseball players that I put into a dataframe. I am filtering out all players who are not in the infield (Pos = 1B, 2B, 3B, SS, IF). I am trying to set some criteria for players I want to drop and replace with better players from a different list.
I was thinking I should add a column onto my dataframe with either yes or no based on the criteria. I would then move those records to a new dataframe. Is this a good way of doing it? I am currently getting this error with my for loop.
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(precision=3,suppress=True)

data = pd.read_excel ("Cleveland roster.xlsx")

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Pos','Name','R','H','HR','RBI','BA','OBP','SLG','OPS'])

df.fillna(data.mean(), inplace=True)

df=df[df['Pos'].isin(['1B','2B','SS','3B','IF'])]

print ('Infielders on the team:')
print (df)
    
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if df['BA'] < .2:
        df.loc[ind, 'KEEP'] = 'No'
    else:
        df.loc[ind, 'KEEP'] = 'Yes'
```

Comment: `df['BA']` is Series, you may want `row['BA']`?

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the error but did not add the yes/no column. I feel like I don't really need that column. I should be able to just move the records that fit the <.2 criteria into the new dataframe without it. Do you see how I could do that?

Comment: I add `df_ = df.loc[df['BA'] < .2]` to my answer, does this suit your need?

Comment: BTW, I couldn't reproduce *did not add the yes/no column* with the iteration.

Comment: I changed my loop. It gave me a new error. TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['BA'] < .2:
        #df['KEEP'] = np.where(df['BA'] < .2, 'No', 'Yes')
        df_ = df.loc[df['BA'] < .2] = 'No'
    else:
        'Yes'

Comment: `df['KEEP'] = np.where(df['BA'] < .2, 'No', 'Yes')` is to replace the whole iteration. Using this line, you don't need the iteration any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to do what you want in one line.

```py
df['KEEP'] = np.where(df['BA'] < .2, 'No', 'Yes')
```

If you want to move the records that fit the <.2 criteria into the new dataframe, you can use boolean indexing.

```py
df_ = df.loc[df['BA'] < .2]
```